# Хранения данных Андроид

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Всем привет. Можно ли как то сохранить информацию так чтобы оно имелось даже после того как приложения будет удалено и заново установлено? Конкретно мне нужно хранить id пользователя.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант сохранять файлы не в папку приложения на external storage

Comment: это в память телефона да?

Comment: Зависит от конкретной модели в некоторых (сейчас большенство) он встроен , на некоторых sd карта

Comment: Не могли бы показать как создать папку и файл json?

Comment: А вообще, если приложение клиент-серверное, то можно юзера не по I'd идентифицировать а по uuid устройства, получить его можно так

Comment: TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String uuid = tManager.getDeviceId();

Comment: а он одинаковым не может быть?

Comment: Вероятность почти ноль

Comment: спасибо наверно так и сделаю

Comment: External storage может быть несколько. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDirs(java.lang.String)